# Проблема с GNOME

Tags: gnome

Я зашёл в KDE Plasma, поработал, потом вышел, зашёл в GNOME и вот (см. фото (пришлось обрезать тк не влезает в 2МБ)) все значки изменились, курсор другой. Что делать? Пока ничего не предпринемал, проблема не гуглится (ну или я хреново гуглю).[image: Проблема]

Comment: А зачем вы ставили гном и кеды на одной системе? Вы же понимаете отличие между DE и WM? DE - это не только способ отрисовки окон, это свой набор программ (включая всякие фоновые демоны), свой стиль и своя идеология.

Answer (score 0):

Сам-же нашёл решение:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Далее заходим в него (tweaks), далее слева вверху будут три прямых, нажимаем на них выбираем пункт "Reset to defaults". Всё сбросится до стандартных настроек окон.